# How to make the bytes random, when writing bytes?

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code, and it writes bytes to a files, although I'd like to know how to make the bytes it writes random from a range (IE, 20-140)
My code:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

var Wfile = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(file, FileMode.Open));
int r = rnd.Next(0, 20);
byte[] bytes = new byte[500 * r];
Wfile.Write(bytes);
Wfile.Close();
```

Comment: Your code, as currently written, only makes the size of the byte array that you are creating random (in a range between 500 and 520 bytes long).  You have to populate the array with random bytes, using a `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`NextBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.random.nextbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from `Random` like this:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[500 * r];
rnd.NextBytes(bytes);
```

The `* r` is not necessarily needed, unless you want also random number of random bytes.

To get bytes from specified range unfortunately you need to generate them manually:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i)
    bytes[i] = (byte)rnd.Next(20, 140);
```

Comment: `NextBytes` does not allow you to specify a range.

Answer (score 1):

Simply fill up your array with randomly generated values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500 * r; ++i)
    bytes[i] = (byte)rnd.Next(20, 140);
```